# Don't kill created processes, which created by ps - linux

Tags: linux, bash

give some advice, please.

I am trying to kill processes remotely (ssh to hostname), find some processes and kill them. But I have a condition: `Do not kill java process, sshd and gnome`.

Here is example (I just do `echo` except `kill`):

```
#/bin/sh -x.
HOSTFILE=$1
vars=`cat $HOSTFILE`
for i in $vars; do
 ssh  "$i" /bin/bash <<'EOF'
  echo $(hostname)
  ps aux | grep -e '^sys_ctl'| grep -v "java" | grep -v "sshd" | \
  grep -v "gnome" | awk '{print $2$11}'|  for i in `xargs echo`; do  echo $i; done;
EOF
done
```

The result is:

```
host1:
21707/bin/bash
21717ps
21718grep
21722awk
21723/bin/bash
21724xargs
host2:
15241/bin/bash
15251ps
15252grep
15256awk
15257/bin/bash
15258xargs
89740-bash
98467sleep
98469sleep
98471sleep
98472sleep
98474sleep
98475sleep
```

I want to kill (`output`), **only** `sleep` processes, **not** `grep,awk,bash,xargs,ps`
Can you suggest something elegant?

Comment: `killall sleep` ? `for i in `xargs echo`; do echo $i` is the strangest thing I have ever seen.

Comment: @KamilCuk  But I can kill all process except `grep,awk,bash,xargs,ps`?

Answer (score 2):

why not just : `kill $(pgrep -f sleep)`
or : `pkill -f sleep`

Comment: I think the `grep -e '^sys_ctl'` is supposed to check the process owner's, so you might want to add a `-U sys_ctl` to the pgrep & pkill (although OP didn't describe this condition, so a clarification would be nice)